# Поясните механизм работы хранимой процедуры MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Пишу хранимую процедуру для последовательной обработки записей в таблице.
Собрал тестовый пример, который на выходе считает количество записей в таблице

```
utsna_virtuemart_product_prices
```

По логике все отрабатывает вроде верно и количество записей обрабатываемых в цикле соответствует количеству записей в таблице.

```
BEGIN

DECLARE iCount BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE _id BIGINT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT virtuemart_product_id FROM utsna_virtuemart_product_prices;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;

OPEN cur;

  testLoop: LOOP
  FETCH cur INTO _id;

    IF done THEN
      LEAVE testLoop;
    END IF;

        SET iCount = iCount + 1;

  END LOOP testLoop;

CLOSE cur;

SELECT iCount;

END
```

Вопрос по коду мне один только не понятен (так как писал по примеру)
Непонятна строка `DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done := TRUE;` и соответственно непонятен механизм, как в условии `IF done THEN` проверяется на наличие истины.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы создаете курсор, открываете его и фетчите из него данные в переменную

```
FETCH cur INTO _id;
```

в какой-то момент записи может не оказаться (был возвращен пустой набор, или мы достигли конца списка). Тогда при фетче возникает некий аналог исключения. Исключение имеет тип `NOT FOUND`. Для этого исключения ищется обработчик и если он найден то выполняется. После этого смотрится на тип обработчика. Если это `CONTINUE` то продолжается выполнение кода. Если `EXIT` то управление передается первому оператору после `END` где был написан обработчик.

Соответственно `done` у Вас равно `FALSE`. Когда записи заканчиваются, ему устанавливается значение `TRUE`, а

```
 IF done THEN
```

просто проверяет значение. И если оно равно `TRUE` то происходит выход за пределы цикла `testLoop`.

С точки зрения читабельности, я бы рекомендовал переписать Ваш код так

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE iCount BIGINT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE done BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
  DECLARE _id BIGINT UNSIGNED;

  DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT virtuemart_product_id FROM utsna_virtuemart_product_prices;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
    SET done := TRUE;

  OPEN cur;
  FETCH cur INTO _id;
  WHILE NOT done DO
    SET iCount = iCount + 1;
    FETCH cur INTO _id;
  END WHILE;
  CLOSE cur;
  SELECT iCount;
END
```

А вместо последнего `SELECT iCount;` рекомендовал бы написать вместо процедуры функцию и возвращать значение